# React JS - browser incognito vs normal mode behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, single-page-application, incognito-mode

I am having strange behaviour in my react app. Steps to reproduce/introduce the problem:

1. Inside react app I am redirecting user to external site using window.location.href
2. Clicking back button inside external site to go back to react app
3. After coming back to react app, page (app) is being loaded but is not being refreshed - even component (page) state is being preserved - same as leaving the app before redirect.

This only happens on production incognito mode (Chrome, Firefox). No issue in development  incognito or normal browsing modes. No issue in production normal mode also.

Is there something that I don't understand or missing, about how my react app is working or differences between incognito and normal modes? Or even server config (aws amplify)?

In normal mode or development, coming back from external site to react app, app works as expected, app/page/component is being rendered properly